# Amazon Product Advertising API Scratchpad not working

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, digital-signature

So I've just been fighting shadows in the Amazon labyrinth. Went to use the [Amazon Product Advertising API Scratchpad](http://webservices.amazon.com/scratchpad/index.html) to test out my `Access Key Id` and `Secret Access Key`, as well as entering the `Associate Tag` which isn't used in critically in the API query, just important if you want credit for the query later.

I kept getting the following error, no matter how many times I went and created a new set of keys or verified them in the download section of the AWS Management Console for the root user - IAM users don't work in the API seemingly.

> Error! SignatureDoesNotMatch
>   HTTP Status 403: Forbidden
>   The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

Rinse and repeat. Many, many times. Complete and utter frustration....

Lo and behold, I come across this oasis of sanity - [Signed Request Helper](http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/signed-requests/helper/index.html) - which provides a successful result to my query with the same keys as used above.

So, can anyone else confirm problems with the Scratchpad that didn't bear out in other applications, like the Signed Request Helper or their own code? At this point I'm betting that there is a bug in the Amazon Scratchpad. I guess I will go roll something to test in Python but the apparent craziness of the URL construction makes me wary. Seemingly it's soo hard even the Amazon guys got it wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who may come across this, let me impart my findings. Importantly, I was able to verify the keys with the [Signed Request Helper](http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/signed-requests/helper/index.html) but wasn't able to get the query to work in the [Scratchpad](http://webservices.amazon.com/scratchpad/index.html). The error received clearly informs me that it is the signature that is wrong:

> Error! SignatureDoesNotMatch HTTP Status 403: Forbidden The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

So one ponders, as instructed, on the Secret Key and the signing method. Since one is using the scratchpad, it must be the key. But the same key works in the signed request helper! What to do.

It turns out that the error was in one of the supplied parameters. If the scratchpad produces a signed url with a faulty parameter, it will result in that error. There is some validation going on, but you can still wind up with a bad parameter. So, if you get the above error, try a simple query with your key to prove that your secret access key is valid, then start investigating your supplied parameter values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this reminds me of the dark days I had trying to get the signature just right.

I too had similar troubles when I started playing with the API. Ultimately, I ended up using the master credentials. [This link](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?rw_useCurrentProtocol=1#security_credential) will take you to the right spot after you login. Open the "Access Keys" tab. This is the area I made a new master access key for signing requests. When you get into the users/groups/roles/policies, I had trouble.

But I have a key there and I can use the scratchpad no problem. I have an application running that uses the key, but I just went and tried a query to confirm it's all still good.

Note that in the scratchpad the Associate Tag is irrelevant like you said. To get the error you have, it's for sure the SECRET ACCESS KEY that is incorrect. If you entered the ACCESS KEY ID field incorrectly, you would get this error:

> Error! InvalidClientTokenId HTTP Status 403: Forbidden The AWS Access
>   Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, it is not the SECRET ACCESS KEY. But thanks for the effort!